# MEAN-Stack - Cannot read second SQL Table from server

Tags: sql, node.js, angular, sequelize.js, mean-stack

I'm developing a WebApp with MEANStack, using Sequelize to access SQL Databases. I managed to read, with the code below, an SQL Table. Unfortunately I get the following error on the client's side when trying to read a second SQL (Edit after first Answer)

```
Table: core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: tableData.processTables.map is not a function at MapSubscriber.project (tables.service.ts:32)
```

tables.service.ts:32 of the error is :

```
        processTables: tableData.processTables.map(table => {
```

And here's how the error on the client's side looks like:
[Table: core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: tableData.processTables.map is not a function at MapSubscriber.project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6V92E.png)

Here's my code (edit)

tables-list.component.html

```
<mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoading"></mat-spinner>
  <h1 class="mat-body-2">Process List &nbsp; </h1>

  <mat-accordion multi="true" *ngIf="userIsAuthenticated && !isLoading">
    <mat-expansion-panel>
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        Process List
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="processTables" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8" *ngIf="userIsAuthenticated">

      <!-- ProcessName Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="ProcessName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ProcessName </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ProcessName}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- PackageVersion Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="PackageVersion">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> PackageVersion </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.PackageVersion}} </td>
        </ng-container>

      <!-- RobotType Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="RobotType">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> RobotType </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.RobotType}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- PackagePath Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="PackagePath">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> PackagePath </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.PackagePath}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- CreationTime Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="CreationTime">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> CreationTime </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.CreationTime}} </td>
        </ng-container>

      <!-- Status Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Status">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Status </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Status}} </td>
        </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedprocessTablesColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedprocessTablesColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>

    <br> <h1 class="mat-body-2">Applications List &nbsp; </h1>
```

tables-list.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { ProcessTable, ApplicationsTable } from "./tables.model";
import { PageEvent } from "@angular/material";

import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
import { TablesService } from "./tables.service";
import { AuthService } from "../auth/auth.service";

@Component({
  // We load the component via routing and therefore we do not need a selector
  selector: "app-tables",
  templateUrl: "./tables-list.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./tables-list.component.css"]
}) // Turn class into component by adding @Component Decorator

export class TableListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  processTables: ProcessTable[] = [];
  applicationsTables: ApplicationsTable[] = [];
  isLoading = false;
  totalTables = 0;
  tablesPerPage = 5;
  currentPage = 1;
  pageSizeOptions = [1, 2, 5, 10];
  displayedprocessTablesColumns: string[] = ["ProcessName", "PackageVersion", "RobotType", "PackagePath", "CreationTime", "Status" ];
  displayedApplicationsTablesColumns: string[] = ["ProcessName", "PackageVersion" ];
  userIsAuthenticated = false;
  userId: string;
  isAdmin: boolean;

  private tablesSub: Subscription;
  private authStatusSub: Subscription;

  constructor(
    public tablesService: TablesService,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.tablesService.getProcessTables(this.tablesPerPage, this.currentPage);
    this.userId = this.authService.getUserId();
    this.tablesSub = this.tablesService
      .getTableUpdateListener()
      .subscribe((tableData: { processTables: ProcessTable[]; applicationsTables: ApplicationsTable[]; tableCount: number }) => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.totalTables = tableData.tableCount;
        this.processTables = tableData.processTables;
        this.applicationsTables = tableData.applicationsTables;
      });
    this.userIsAuthenticated = this.authService.getIsAuth();
    // console.log("Is authenticated: " + this.userIsAuthenticated);
    this.authStatusSub = this.authService
      .getAuthStatusListener()
      .subscribe(isAuthenticated => {
        this.userIsAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
      });
  }

  onLogout() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.tablesSub.unsubscribe();
    this.authStatusSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Tables.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

import { environment } from "../../environments/environment";
import { ProcessTable, ApplicationsTable } from "./tables.model";

const BACKEND_URL = environment.apiUrl + "/tables/";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class TablesService {
  private processTables: ProcessTable[] = [];
  private applicationsTables: ApplicationsTable[] = [];
  private tablesUpdated = new Subject<{ processTables: ProcessTable[]; applicationsTables: ApplicationsTable[]; tableCount: number }>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

  getProcessTables(tablesPerPage: number, currentPage: number) {
    const queryParams = `?pagesize=${tablesPerPage}&page=${currentPage}`;
    this.http
      .get<{ processTables: ProcessTable[]; applicationsTables: ApplicationsTable[]; maxTables: number }>(
        BACKEND_URL + queryParams
      )
      .pipe(
        map((tableData: { processTables: ProcessTable[]; applicationsTables: ApplicationsTable[]; maxTables: number }) => {
          console.log(tableData);
          console.log(tableData.processTables);
          console.log(tableData.applicationsTables);
          return {
            processTables: tableData.processTables.map(table => {
              return {
                ProcessName: table.ProcessName,
                PackageVersion: table.PackageVersion,
                RobotType: table.RobotType,
                PackagePath: table.PackagePath,
                CreationTime: table.CreationTime,
                Status: table.Status
              };
            }),
             applicationsTables: tableData.applicationsTables.map(table => {
              return {
                ProcessName: table.ProcessName,
                PackageVersion: table.PackageVersion,
                WorkflowsBelongingToProcess: table.WorkflowsBelongingToProcess,
                ApplicationsBelongingToWorkflow: table.ApplicationsBelongingToWorkflow
              };
            }),
            maxTables: tableData.maxTables
          };
        })
      )
      .subscribe(transformedTablesData => {
        this.processTables = transformedTablesData.processTables;
        this.tablesUpdated.next({
          processTables: [...this.processTables],
          applicationsTables: [...this.applicationsTables],
          tableCount: transformedTablesData.maxTables
        });
      });
  }

  getTableUpdateListener() {
    return this.tablesUpdated.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Tables\model.ts:

```
export interface Table {
  ProcessName: string;
  PackageVersion: string;
  RobotType: string;
  PackagePath: string;
  CreationTime: string;
  Status: string;
}

export interface ApplicationsTable {
  ProcessName: string;
  PackageVersion: string;
  WorkflowsBelongingToProcess: string;
  ApplicationsBelongingToWorkflow: string;
}
```

Backend\controllers\tables.js:

```
const sequelize = require("../sequelize");

const getProcessTables = (req, res) => {
  return sequelize
    .query("SELECT * FROM dbo.Process", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })
    .then(fetchedtables => {
      return {
        message: "Process table fetched from the server",
        processTables: fetchedtables,
        maxProcessTables: fetchedtables.length
      };
    });
};

const getApplicationsTables = (req, res) => {
  return sequelize
    .query("SELECT * FROM dbo.Applications", {
      type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
    })
    .then(fetchedtables => {
      return {
        message: "Applications Table fetched from the server",
        applicationsTables: fetchedtables,
        maxApplicationsTables: fetchedtables.length
      };
    });
};

exports.getAllTables = (req, res) => {
  return Promise.all([
    getApplicationsTables(req, res),
    getProcessTables(req, res)
  ]).then(tables => {
    res.status(200).json({
      applicationsTables: tables[0],
      processTables: tables[1]
    });
  });
};
```

Backend\routes\tables.js:

```
const express = require("express");

const TableController = require("../controllers/tables")

const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });

router.get("", TableController.getAllTables);

module.exports = router;
```

How can I fix it?
Many Thanks
Gennaro

Comment: @GeraintAnderson any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors that I can see.

- You are querying the `/tables/` route but not defining the route.
- You Created two request handler and used the same route. What is does is the request goes to the first `app.get` block. Not the second one.

So, first you need to Merge the getProcessTable and getApplicationTable into one consolidated function.

```
const sequelize = require("../sequelize");

const getProcessTables = (req, res) => {
  return sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM dbo.Process", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
  .then(fetchedtables => {
    return {
      message: "Process table fetched from the server",
      processTables: fetchedtables,
      maxProcessTables: fetchedtables.length
    };
  });
};

const getApplicationsTables = (req, res) => {
  return sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM dbo.Applications", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
  .then(fetchedtables => {
    return {
      message: "Applications Table fetched from the server",
      applicationsTables: fetchedtables,
      maxApplicationsTables: fetchedtables.length
    };
  });
};

exports.getAllTables = (req, res) =>{
    return Promise.all([getApplicationsTables(req,res), getProcessTables(req,res)])
    .then(tables =>{
        res.status(200).json({
            applicationsTables: tables[0],
            processTables: tables[1]
          });
    })
}
```

and then maybe route it to tables

```
router.get("/tables/", TableController.getAllTables);
```

Now, you need to change the `map` line.

`processTables: tableData.processTables.map` will be,

```
processTables: tableData.processTables.processTables.map(table => {
```

Comment: Hi @Aritra, thanks for your super reply. I have implemented your changes and also edited my original post accordingly. It does not work yet and actually now I'm no longer able to read the Process Data Table either. I posted the error as well as image attached. As you can see, ProcessTable is read at least in tables.service, but ApplicationsTable is "undefined" (console logs on lines 28 and 29 of tables.service) What can it be? Thanks, G.

Comment: there was a typo in my code. I typed `applicationTables` instead of `applicationsTables`.. (notice the `S`). Edited Answer.

Comment: Hi @Aritra, thanks for your reply. That's amazing because now we can read both tables. However the error didn't go. Please look at my updated code above and also at my updated screenshot, where you can see the same error but you can also see that now both tables are read.

At the moment neither tables load. What is the cause of this problem?

Comment: that's because you are iterating the parent object. Map is a function of an array. Now, the `table.applicationTables` is an object. so you need to do `table. applicationsTables.applicationsTables.map`, Edited Answer

Comment: Hi  @Aritra Chakraborty any ideas?

Comment: You have to do the process tables as well as application table. did you do the same for process table? are you even debugging the code? it's pretty simple error and the error msg is self explanatory as well.

Comment: Yes I am debugging the code. If I try table.processTables.processTables.map, it says: [ts] Property 'processTables' does not exist on type 'ProcessTable[]'. [2339]. Some posts on the internet mention the need to convert Object into Array, but my attempts were unsuccessful.

Comment: Hi @Aritra, so the code works fine as per your suggestions. Thanks. However Visual Studio Code keeps complaning, despite the fact that the code works just fine, returning the error [ts] Property 'processTables' does not exist on type 'ProcessTable[]'. [2339]. How can I fix it?

Comment: Because of this `processTables: ProcessTable[] = [];
  applicationsTables: ApplicationsTable[] = [];` you are specifying a type. make it `any` or something. it will not throw error

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for solving this!

Comment: Hello @Aritra, as you were so fast and expert at solving this, maybe you could help me on this other issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53647928/meanstack-angular-table-sorting-and-pagination-functionalities. Many thanks